# React Native TV, Unwanted Focusing on Text element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

For a react native tv application using react-native-template-typescript-tv / react-native-tvos

The first focus is on **Text** and on press down it is focusing on the **TouchableHighlight**
How do I prevent the focus on a Text element?

I tried adding the prop `focusable={false}` and fiddled with the `hasTVPreferredFocus`

```
<View>
  <Text>Title</Text>
  <TouchableHighlight>Click Me</TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```